# Set-Cookie not setting cookie though received in the response from web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement the antiforgerytoken validation between my angular application and .net core 3.1 web api.

I have added the antiforgerytoken validation as per the process mentioned in the below link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/preventing-csrf-attacks-using-asp-net-core-javascript-and-angular/

I can see the Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=somebigchunkofdata in the response from my authenticate call. But when the angular is trying to read the same cookie in interceptor, it is empty

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";  
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor } from "@angular/common/http";  
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";  
import { Observable } from "rxjs";  
  
  
@Injectable()  
export class XsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {  
  constructor(private xsrfTokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {  
  }  
  
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {  
    // load token  
    let xsrfToken = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken();  
  
    if (xsrfToken != null) {  
      // create a copy of the request and  
      // append the XSRF token to the headers list  
      const authorizedRequest = req.clone({  
        withCredentials: true,  
        headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken)  
      });  
  
      return next.handle(authorizedRequest);  
    } else {  
      return next.handle(req);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

both are running in localhost, but the port numbers are different. However in production the domain names also will be different.

Answer (score 0):

you doesn't need to add the token in the request you can do it directly before in the HttpClient for example a post:

```
var requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
let xsrfToken = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken() as string; 
requestHeaders = requestHeaders.set('XSRF_HEADER_TOKEN', xsrfToken);
  return this.httpClient.post<YourClass>("/api/yourclass", addedclass, {headers: requestHeaders,  responseType: "json" });
```

in order to get the cookie in your browser because you are using absolute paths, you need to set in the AddAntiforgery httponly false, samesite none, secure SameAsRequest as the linked you provided, when you see the response you will in the browser Inspect, you will see added a set-cookie, if the cookie isn't added is because what I described before.
Also, you don't need to add options.Cookie.Name in the AddAntiforgery just let it default because Configure you will add it again and it can't have the same name(it's a .net thing)

In the Configure in the link you provided should be like this

```
  app.Use((context, next) =>  
  {  
    // return current accessed path  
    string path = context.Request.Path.Value;  
  
    if (path != null && !path.ToLower().Contains("/api")) //better like this so it will get fr "/" only.  
    {  
      var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);  
      context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-COOKIENAME-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, // //can be the same as options.Cookie.Name  
        new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false, Secure = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });
    }  
  
    return next();  
  });
```

and add in your app module imports

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'XSRF-COOKIENAME-TOKEN',
  headerName: 'XSRF_HEADER_TOKEN'
  })
```

Update, And needs to add AllowCredentials() in the cors.
this is the way.